# Inserir valor na tabela sql usando "parte" do formulario

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho um formulário para cadastro de receitas. Quando finalizo o cadastro, a receita é adicionada na tabela "receitas". Todos os ingredientes também estão em uma tabela separada chamada "ingredientes".

O meu form está assim:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="receita" id="receita">
<input type="text" name="ingrediente" id="ingrediente">
<button id="addingrediente">Adicionar ingrediente</button>
<input type="textarea" name="ingredientes" id="ingredientes">
</form>
```

Eu tenho já um script que faz consulta no banco de dados, conforme escreve o ingrediente ele traz o nome e ao clicar em cima do nome ele adiciona no campo ingredientes.

Aí queria que, se ele não encontrar o ingrediente, ao clicar em Adicionar ingrediente, ele pegasse o valor que está no campo ingrediente e adicionasse na tabela "ingredientes".

Comment: Coloque o código do `addingrediente`

Comment: é só fazer um `if` do retorno da consulta dos ingredientes, e verificar se o result set tem count = 0

Comment: E se o campo estiver vazio?

Comment: Se não encontrar nada o campo vai ficar vazio. O que o JavaScript tem a ver com isso? Está usando Ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Adicione no seu script de busca, a ação de cadastrar o ingrediente que está sendo buscado no bd quando o **resultado da busca retornar 0** && **empty($ingrediente) == false**.
Sendo assim, ele irá cadastrar o valor do ingrediente apenas se o ingrediente não foi encontrado na busca e seu valor é diferente de vazio.
Por ultimo é só usar o Ajax pra inserir o valor do ingrediente no textarea ficaria algo mais ou menos assim usando apenas JavaScript: "document.getElementById(campo).innerHTML=ingrediente"